# Sublime plug-in works only if I don't restart Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I'm trying to fix a *[reported bug](https://github.com/vitto/sublime-theme-automator/issues/2)* for a Plug-in I've wrote named *[ThemeAutomator](https://github.com/vitto/sublime-theme-automator/blob/master/ThemeAutomator.py)* but I'm not sure I get what's the problem.

if I `print` my loaded plug-in's sublime settings it works only on first run install, or when I save [ThemeAutomator.py](https://github.com/vitto/sublime-theme-automator/blob/master/ThemeAutomator.py), basically sublime reloads it and then it works. The method `load_settings` doesn't load the right data enymore, why?

First install

```
print(sublime.load_settings('ThemeAutomator.sublime-settings').get('schemes')
```

returns `[]`, an empty array ready to be populated, if I use the plug in, i see I populate `ThemeAutomator.sublime-settings` correctly with data like `{'extension': '.md', 'color_scheme': 'Packages/...`

---

after I reload Sublime

returns `NoneType`

Here is the full stack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Coding/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/sublime_plugin.py", line 303, in on_activated
    callback.on_activated(v)
  File "ThemeAutomator in /Users/coop/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages/ThemeAutomator.sublime-package", line 64, in on_activated
  File "ThemeAutomator in /Users/coop/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages/ThemeAutomator.sublime-package", line 41, in add_scheme
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
found 12 files for base name Main.sublime-menu
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Coding/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/sublime_plugin.py", line 319, in on_deactivated
    callback.on_deactivated(v)
  File "ThemeAutomator in /Users/coop/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages/ThemeAutomator.sublime-package", line 69, in on_deactivated
  File "ThemeAutomator in /Users/coop/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages/ThemeAutomator.sublime-package", line 51, in set_scheme_for_extension
  File "ThemeAutomator in /Users/coop/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages/ThemeAutomator.sublime-package", line 41, in add_scheme
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

what's wrong with the plug-in?

You can check the [code of the plug-in here](https://github.com/vitto/sublime-theme-automator/blob/master/ThemeAutomator.py)

Comment: Could you post the error thats being thrown?